# Javascript click event not reverting according to my statement

Tags: javascript, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to revert my click event after clicking but my else statement seems not to be working, I do not know if something is wrong with my code:

```
var img = document.querySelector ('.change');

img.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(img.src = 'homepage imgs/inactive.svg') {
        img.src = 'homepage imgs/like icon.svg';
    } else{
        img.src = 'homepage imgs/inactive.svg';
    }
});
```

Comment: You have `=` in the `if` statement where you meant to put `==(=)`

Comment: You can't use assignment in your `if()` you need to use proper conditional ... which in your case should be `img.src === 'homepage imgs/inactive.svg'`. You should always check your code before you post because this was a simple mistake that is so easy to pick up.

Comment: To make sure you don't repeat such mistake, read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: I know and I did check my code, the only reason I assigned it was because comparing it did not work as to assigning it where it actually did work, but my else statement did not work, I did try your solution, but it still did not work.

Answer (score -1):

you are actually assigning rather than comparing
a single = is used to assign like

```
a = 10;
```

a double == is used for comparison, like whether a is equal to 10 or not

```
like a==10;
```

to fix your issue change to

```
if(img.src == 'homepage imgs/inactive.svg')
```